need to collect image id attribute while onclick function is not working, unable to find fault
Please help,
I don't understand what's wrong. when I click on the images nothing happens. onclick="collectImageId(this.id) doesn't seems to work. I checked everything up to my knowledge but couldn't find what's missing! can somebody help me to find the fault?
THE CODE IS TO COLLECT IMAGE IDs (my target project is to collect image ids from random 1000 images, this is just the mini version of the entire code)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Collect Image IDs on Click</title>
    <script>
        // Global variable to store the last clicked image ID
        var lastClickedImageId = "";

        // Function to collect and store the image ID when clicked
        function collectImageId(imageId) {
            lastClickedImageId = imageId; // Save the clicked image ID
            console.log("Last clicked image ID:", lastClickedImageId);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Image 1 -->
<img id="image1" src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" onclick="collectImageId(this.id)">

<!-- Image 2 -->
<img id="image2" src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" onclick="collectImageId(this.id)">

<!-- Image 3 -->
<img id="image3" src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3" onclick="collectImageId(this.id)">

<!-- Display last clicked image ID -->
<p>Last clicked image ID: <span id="lastClickedIdDisplay"></span></p>

<script>
    // Function to update the display of last clicked image ID
    function updateLastClickedIdDisplay() {
        document.getElementById('lastClickedIdDisplay').textContent = lastClickedImageId;
    }

    // Add event listeners to update the display when the global variable changes
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'lastClickedImageId', {
        set: function(value) {
            lastClickedImageId = value;
            updateLastClickedIdDisplay();
        },
        get: function() {
            return lastClickedImageId;
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>`


I tried to find the fault. But unable find what is wrong, why the code is not working? why if the image is clicked nothing happens? --- I expect the code to run smoothly and collect image id attribute whenever clicked.

When I run your code, clicking on an image does log to the console. So I can't reproduce your problem.

Also Object.defineProperty(window, 'lastClickedImageId' won't work for a variable defined with var as it'll be non-configurable. You'll see an error in the console saying that it can't be redefined. Instead, call updateLastClickedIdDisplay() in your event listener instead.

You might want to simplify your code.
You can also display the id of the clicked image on the same function where you collected it.
Your JS should be like this:
    // Function to collect and store the image ID when clicked
    function collectImageId(imageId) {
        let display = document.getElementById('lastClickedIdDisplay');
        display.innerHTML = "<br>" + imageId + display.innerHTML;
        console.log("Last clicked image ID:", imageId);
    }

Note that I also removed the other scripts at the bottom script tag and transferred your collectImageId function there because JS is mostly placed there not in the head tag (that's CSS).
Here is the working code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Collect Image IDs on Click</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Image 1 -->
<img id="image1" src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" onclick="collectImageId(this.id)">

<!-- Image 2 -->
<img id="image2" src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" onclick="collectImageId(this.id)">

<!-- Image 3 -->
<img id="image3" src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3" onclick="collectImageId(this.id)">

<!-- Display last clicked image ID -->
<p>Last clicked image ID: <span id="lastClickedIdDisplay"></span></p>

<script>
    // Function to collect and store the image ID when clicked
    function collectImageId(imageId) {
        let display = document.getElementById('lastClickedIdDisplay');
        display.innerHTML = "<br>" + imageId + display.innerHTML;
        console.log("Last clicked image ID:", imageId);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>




Your code worked! but in my chrome browser I only see the id of which I just clicked (which is pretty much ok, enough for my project) but it doesn't show the exact result  list of all the clicked images' ids, just as we get in the "Run code snippet." --- this is not an issue to my project, the code just gives two different output in two different place --- that's all!!!

console.log("Last clicked image ID:", lastClickedImageId);
this line is not working. if  I comment it out, still the code runs as same like before. I don't know its a chrome browser issue or not! but console.log doesn't seems to give output, I checked on one of my other code. why? any idea?

@Mzi for your first comment, I already modified the answer. Run it again.

For your second comment, console.log will not display anything in the page. That's only for logging purposes in the browser's console.

Man!!!! this is just too good to be true... thanks soo much :)    @Christian
